# AsyncTask loop not executed after adding Listener

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listener

I'm trying to get a response back from my public class saveData extends AsyncTask.

For that I have added a `public interface OnTaskCompleted()`.But the for loop does not get executed and it is going straight from the for line to the return and `onPostExecute()` never get executed. If I remove the interface the loop it is working properly.

*My Activity:*

```
public class almostFinish extends Activity{

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}

private void InvoiceSave(){
SaveMyData savedata = new SaveMyData(new OnTaskCompleted() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTaskCompleted(boolean isSuccess) {
                            if(isSuccess){
                                //do something
                            }
                            else {
                                showMyAlert("Error Saving Invoice!");
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
                    ...
                    savedata.execute(myList);
 }
```

My interface.

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
void onTaskCompleted(boolean isSuccess);
}
```

My AsyncTask class

```
public class SaveMyData extends AsyncTask<List<String>, Void, Void> {
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;
    boolean myflag = false;

 public SaveMyData (OnTaskCompleted listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}

 @Override
public void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(List<String>... params) {
      for (int i = 1; i == 5; i++) {
      }
 return null;
}

 @Override
public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

        listener.onTaskCompleted(myflag);

}
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: excute method was not called

Comment: your `constructor`'s name `saveInvDetails` is different from class name `saveData`

Comment: Sorry that was type error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition you set for the loop is wrong. Shouldn't it be `for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)`??

Comment: I had it as < 5 and it need it to go to 5 so enter == which of course translate to the loop only run if i is 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as @Mr Neo said and the constructor and the class name should be the same, for example:

```
public class saveData extends AsyncTask<List<String>, Void, Void> {
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;
    boolean myflag = false;

public saveData(OnTaskCompleted listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}
```

Other thing, the class name should be started with a capital letter like "SaveData", and a non-static member declaration name should be started with a non-capital letter, like "saveData", for example:

```
SaveData saveData = new SaveData(someParams);
saveData.execute(otherSomeParams);
```

Good coding manner makes a good developer aha.

Comment: 'and a non-static member declaration name'... Well i would say: and the name of an instance of that class should be started...

Comment: @greeapps thanks for helping on my english. I am a non-english speaker and is not a guy lives in english speaking country, and I dropped out from the college. So forget about my english. :)

Comment: Sorry a typing error in the question the original code is correct. I have corrected it but as you can see in my question everything works fine if I remove the listner.